# How to upgrade Google Play Services on emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

We have installed `com.android.vending` and `com.google.android.gms` files. 
Now we have got that warning

> "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services".

What should we do now, what is emulator try to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application requires higher version of Google Play Services than you have installed on emulator. You should check this link: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
Specific information is:

> Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform. If you want
>   to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for Android
>   4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target.

You should create emulator as fresh as possible (API 19).

Answer (score 0):

`adb install -r com.google.android.gms-4.3.23.apk`

go to [google play service 4323000](https://mega.co.nz/#!JEJ02Jia!XL_hjlxFqf_g9-pJH7DY6GDmAzESJb0aZQ_c8JWo_KI)